# How to let the user to switch from list layout to grid layout on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have to show a list of grouped (sections) items. The user can choose the way the items are been showed on screen: List layout or Grid layout.

In the past I have done it by setting dynamically the span count of a gridviewlayout: When the span count was 1, I returned the view type of a list element. When it was > 1, I returned the view type for a grid view. Something like this https://medium.com/xorum-io/android-recyclerview-animated-transition-between-grid-and-list-layouts-b2309e1d9f19.

Now I'm migrating from the no longer maintained com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview to groupie.

But is possible to do this things using groupie ?

Comment: How about  changing layoutmanager of recylerview i.e., between LinearLayoutManager and GridLayoutManager. To change item layout you can use viewtype in adapter.

Comment: Hi !
Thanks to the answer :)
in groupie is it possible ?
Because I need to create a sectioned recycler view and groupie do it very well.